# What is causing undefined control sequence

Tags: errors

I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined control sequence
1.67 ....ideology function $v_1 : A \to \R$, that represents....
```

which is from:

```
$v_i : A \to \R$
```

And this is my header:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath,endnotes}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
```

Can somebody help me out with this one.

Comment: Note that the original error message would have had the undefined command as the last the last thing on the first line of the message. You have reformatted it to hide that information so we are having to guess which command is undefined, presumably `\R`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the macro `\R` defined. Presumably you want to represent a mapping from (the set `A` to the real domain. The latter is commonly defined using `\mathbb{R}`. As such, it would suffice to define

```
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
```

in your preamble:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}
$v_i : A \to \R$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\colon` would be better suited here instead of `:`.